# Правильно ли сказано?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Для предотвращения образования отложений солей **двух- и более валентных ионов** в порах мембран..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это конструкция с однородными членами, имеющими общий конечный элемент. Если все члены, кроме последнего, представлены только начальными элементами, то после них используется "висячий" дефис: *не двух-, а трёхэтажный дом; не только англо- и франко-, но и русскоязычные тексты*.  В вашем случае однородные члены имеют разное строение (сложное слово и словосочетание), но, как мне кажется, выбранная вами пунктуация логична.